# Fixed background image bug Chrome Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I'm building a website that uses fixed background images to transition between sections. Currently, it is pure CSS. The effect works on every browser that I've tested it in, except for one: Chrome on Mac (Version 33.0.1750.146 or Version 34.0.1847.45 beta). Seems to work fine on Chrome on PC.

What happens is pretty strange...on scroll, the image is repeated and overlayed and overall very distorted. After a bit more scroll, it disappears. It does not reappear on scroll up.

Any ideas or solutions?!

Current page: http://margusity.com/follies-beta

Current screenshot (broken, chrome): http://cloud.ikilledtheinter.net/ULra

Current screenshot (working, safari): http://cloud.ikilledtheinter.net/ULxH

Seemingly relevant CSS:

```
.chris, .eric,  {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chris {
  background-image: url(../img/people/chris.png);
}

.eric {
  background-image: url(../img/people/eric.png);
}
```

Edit: It seems to be the fixed background element that is causing the issue. Removing "position:fixed" from #behind (css not shown above) fixes the issue above, but does not solve my requirements. Working on a solution now!

Comment: I am using Chrome on Mac (Version 33.0.1750.146), i dont see any issue

Comment: @VikasGhodke Would you mind taking a screenshot of what it looks like to you?? This is confusing me a lot...I had a friend test it on his Mac in Chrome and it looked the same as on mine... (But we are both on Mavericks, with retina)

Comment: Here you go --> http://s14.postimg.org/npylargep/screenshot_47.jpg and here is my chrome version http://postimg.org/image/vviz95y2b/

Comment: Damn, this is very strange. What OS, @VikasGhodke?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into this same issue. It looks like your site is working now, can you share your solution?

EDIT: Removing `position: relative;` and setting the html and body to both have `height: 100%;` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Switching an unnested position:fixed element out fixed the problem. I'm not sure why.
To fully solve the problem, I set the body to contain an attachment:fixed background image that the other elements all scrolled over, with their respective attachment:fixed background images. I would however like to know why the original failed in only Chrome on Mac on some browsers, yet worked everywhere else -__-

Comment: I think it's a Chrome + Mac + Retina bug

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 38 Canary, Windows 8.1

Same Error: http://puu.sh/aOKEH/77538a9a01.jpg

Many other Pages bug out too.. (Twitter Fixed Background for example)