# Background while fixed scroling choppy on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos

I have a question about fixed background issues on Mac.

Background is appearing choppy on Safari Mac, client reported this, I am on Windows 7, and it looks good in every browser.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Here is my website

http://www.barrusinjurylawyers.com/

and the background code :

```
    body {
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url('http://www.barrusinjurylawyers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/SA-Color-Mesh-1680x1050-72dpi1.jpg') no-repeat center center  fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this question. I think it might be a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292357/fixed-background-image-bug-chrome-mac

Comment: Thanks, I will..
It is so anoying